# Which is better: Many files or a singular file with a lot of data

Tags: json

I am working with a lot of separate data entries and unfortunately do not know SQL, so I need to know which is the faster method of storing data.

I have several hundred, if not in the thousands, individual files storing user data. In this case they are all lists of Strings and nothing else, so I have been listing them line by line as such, accessing the files as needed. Encryption is not necessary.

```
test
buyhome
foo
etc. (About 75 or so entries)
```

More recently I have learned how to use JSON and had this question: Would it be faster to leave these as individual files to read as necessary, or as a very large JSON file I can keep in memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In memory access will **always** be much faster than disk access, however if your in memory data is modified and the system crashes you will **lose** that data if it has not been saved to a form of persistent data storage.

Given the amount of data you say you are working with, you really should be using a database of some sort. Either drop everything and go learn some [SQL](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql.htm) (the basics are not that hard) or leverage what you know about JSON and look into a NoSQL database like [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/).

You will find that using the right tool for the job often saves you more time in the long run than trying to force the tool you currently have to work. Even if you need to invest some time upfront to learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is: DO NOT keep data in memory. Unless you are creating portal like SO or Reddit, RAM as a storage is a bad idea.

Second thing is: reading a file is slow. Opening and closing a file is slow too. Try to keep number of files as low as possible.

If you are gonna use each and every of those files (key issue is EVERY), keep them together. If you will only need some of them, store them separately.

Comment: Keeping data in memory isn't necessary bad. Without further information on what kind of programm Ethan is working, a general recommendation to not keep data in memory is misleading.

Comment: He doesn't know SQL - this means that he has some learning ahead of him. At this point of his long road "dont keep data in memory" is a general tip that will make his life easier. There are some cases when its OK to do it, but he would probably need more experience and knowledge to handle them. @Ethan Z: No offence, it's important that you're learning, not that you haven't learned everything yet.

Comment: @fillip, I'm only a high school student, so this is only in my free time. I would love to learn SQL, but it's more time I don't have right now.

Comment: Sure, I get it, I was in similiar situation ;)